# How to add space Between Columns in Bar chartjs and remove the space in the end

Tags: charts, chart.js

**Space between column in chart js**
There's the screen of my output and what i want to do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLsMb.png)

Anyone can help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the `barPercentage` property

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        barPercentage: 0.3

      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        barPercentage: 0.3

      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: i've already done this, but i don't know why i always get the space in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have something like this but i need to add space between each column